# Why is PhpSpreadSheet reading thousands like decimals?

Tags: php, format, phpspreadsheet

I´m trying to read a number from a formula from an .xlsx file using:

```
$value1 = number_format($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('T63')->getOldCalculatedValue(), 0);
```

Then, I want to insert that value into mysql database and I can´t for the following reason. For example, if the value of the cell T63 is 1234, getOldCalculatedValue() returns 1,234 , and mysql reads it like a double. So I need to get that value without the comma. Is it any mode to do it?

PD: I´ve already probe all of this and it does not work for me:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('T63')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

I´ve also tried this:

```
$value1 = str_replace(',', '.', number_format($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('T63')->getOldCalculatedValue(), 0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop `number_format` to retrieve the number without separator:

e.g. change

```
// output: 1,234
$value1 = number_format($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('T63')->getOldCalculatedValue(), 0);
```

to

```
// output: 1234
$value1 = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('T63')->getOldCalculatedValue();
```